# How to implement customized form with CreateView class

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-forms, django-views

I would like to build creation object form using CreateView class , but when using it i don't have much customization ,at least i don't know how

html code

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p}}
</form>
```

I know i can add some bootstrap class like

```
    from django.forms import TextInput, Textarea

class MyForm(modelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            "name": TextInput({"class": "form-control"}),
            "comment": Textarea({"data-validation": "validate"}),
        }
```

But i don't know hot do more "complex" staff like input-group-prepend with icon and get eventually form similar to image attached in example
[form example[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If6wX.jpg)

Please advice

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/). Just render the field manually one by one in the structure that you want. Also you can render fields manually without widget-tweaks you will have to add attributes using javascript or jquery and css.

You can find the classes easily using the inspect tool in the browser.